# XSLT 2.0 support in JDK 6?

Tags: java, java-6, xslt-2.0

Does JDK 6 support XSLT 2.0 for transformation.

My question is, does it come with an XSLT processor built for XSLT 2.0? or DO I need to go for other libraries like Saxon.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't, not by default anyway. As you suggest, you need to use [Saxon](http://www.sf.net/projects/saxon) or another option would be [Oracle's XDK](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/xml/xdkhome.html).