# Applying XSLT v. 2 on XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I had written an XSLT 2.0 version file and when it is applied to an XML file it gives me following error:

```
ERROR:  'Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:sequence''
```

This is the Java code:

```
   TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("Test.xslt"));
   transformer.transform(new StreamSource("Old.xml"),new StreamResult(new    
   FileOutputStream("New.xml")));
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: could you publish your xslt aswell ?

Comment: How does your Test.xslt look like

Answer (score 3):

The default XSLT processors in java do not yet support `XSLT 2.0`. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599957/xslt-2-0-support-in-jdk-6)

You either need to stick with XSLT 1.0, or find a [XSLT processor that supports XSLT 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515979/java-xslt-processors-supporting-xpath-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to your code

```
System.setProperty( 
"javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory","net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

Note: Also add corresponding JAR files for the Saxon parser than you will be good to go. You can refer [this link](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.4/) for JAR file references. Hope this will help.